# Utilizar imagen de la carpeta Resources C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, itextsharp

Requiero usar una imagen (x.png) de la carpeta Resources de la solución para ingresarla en un .PDF usando el NuGet iTextSharp (v5.5.13).

Normalmente lo cargaría así, en caso de ser una dirección de la maquina.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image tif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\Users\\Lelo-Magdiel\\Desktop\\x.png");
```

¿Es posible?
¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Mil Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer igual pero poniendo una ruta relativa que no te dará problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trata con lo siguiente: convertir la imagen en un arreglo de bytes, luego obtener su instancia, para finalizar agregándolo al documento:

```
byte[] bytesImagen = new system.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(Resources.X, typeof(byte[])) as byte[];
Image imagen = Image.GetInstance(bytesImagen);
document.add(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que tienes la imagen en el `Resources`del mismo proyecto quedaría algo así:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image tif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Resources.Foto, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Donde `Foto` es **el nombre de la imagen** que le has asignado al añadirla al `Resources`.

Un saludo y espero que te pueda ayudar.